# jQuery: if a field hasClass, count words in other field

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to write a function that would check if `.toggle` has class `.active`, then it would count the words in `.hidden` and add `margin-bottom` to `.portrait-wrapper` accordingly.

This is not working:

```
$(function(){
    $('.toggle').click(function(){
        $( ".toggle" ).hasClass( '.active', function (){
            var n = $(".hidden").length;
            if (n > 1400) {
                $(".portrait-wrapper").css("margin-bottom", "500px");
            } 
            else {
                $(".portrait-wrapper").css("margin-bottom", "100px");
            }
        });
```

Any guidance would be appreciated.

O.

Comment: Two problems. 1) [hasClass shouldn't include a "." and returns a boolean](http://api.jquery.com/hasclass/); 2) You count words wrong. Use `$(".hidden").text().split(" ").length`.

Comment: I made an answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/27980675/1080564

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I posted in a comment, there are two problems:

- [hasClass shouldn't include a "." and returns a boolean](http://api.jquery.com/hasclass/)
- You count words wrong. Use `$(".hidden").text().trim().split(" ").length`. Read about [`.text()`](http://api.jquery.com/text/), [`String.prototype.trim()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/Trim) and [`String.prototype.split()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split)

The result would look like this:

```
$('.toggle').click(function() {
    if($(".toggle").hasClass('active')) {
        var n = $(".hidden").text().trim().split(" ").length;
        if (n > 1400) {
            $(".portrait-wrapper").css("margin-bottom", "500px");
        } 
        else {
            $(".portrait-wrapper").css("margin-bottom", "100px");
        }
    }
});
```

To elaborate: in your example you use `$(".hidden").length`. This returns the number of elements matched by `".hidden"`, but has nothing to do with the contents of the field.

Answer (score 4):

`hasClass` returns a boolean, so you need to use it in an if statement. Also When you find a class please dont use `.` notation

```
if($( ".toggle" ).hasClass( 'active')){
    var n = $(".hidden").text().split(" ").length;
    if (n > 1400) {
        $(".portrait-wrapper").css("margin-bottom", "500px");
    } 
    else {
        $(".portrait-wrapper").css("margin-bottom", "100px");
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, worked nicely. How would one remove the margin if .toggle does not have class .active anymore? It is toggled

Comment: I dint understand...which class you want to remove and from where?

Comment: If the class .active is removed from .toggle, the margin does not return to it's original value in the css file. How would I achieve this

Comment: Change the margin when you remove the class .active

Comment: You didn't correctly answer the question. Your snippet still does not test correctly for number of words in `.hidden`.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use "." class selector within the "hasClass" function. It already counts with it:

http://api.jquery.com/hasclass/

```
if ($( ".toggle" ).hasClass('active')) {
}
```

Comment: You do not answer the part about counting words.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't use the `.`-notation when using the hasClass function.
See: [hasClass docs](http://api.jquery.com/hasclass/)

Comment: In addition, `hasClass` returns a boolean (does not take a callback) and you count words wrong.

Comment: actually wanted to point out the class thing and just copy pasted the code, was too quick. edited it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
.hasClass(className)
```

Method does not take a `function` as second parameter.
As [doc](http://api.jquery.com/hasclass/) says:

> .hasClass( className )
>   className
>   Type: String
>   The class name to search for.

Do something like:

```
$(".toggle").click(function(){
   $(this).hasClass("active") && doTheTrick(); 
   //same as if($(this).hasClass("active)) doTheTrick()
})

function doTheTrick(){
  var n = $(".hidden").text().trim().split(" ").length;
  var margin = n > 1400 ? "500px" : "100px";
  $(".portrait-wrapper").css("margin-bottom", margin)

});
```

Answer (score -2):

you mis used .hasClass function
maybe it should be like this

```
$(function(){
    $('.toggle').click(function(){
        if ($( ".toggle" ).hasClass('active'))
        {
            var n = $(".hidden").length;
            if (n > 1400) {
                $(".portrait-wrapper").css("margin-bottom", "500px");
            } 
            else {
                $(".portrait-wrapper").css("margin-bottom", "100px");
            }

        };
    });
});
```

Comment: hasClass's argument should not have a `.` in front. It should be `.hasClass('active')`. In addition, you still do not count words in `.hidden`.